# filter record in dataframe base on list of value

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have below scenario.

```
li = ['g1','g2','g3']
df1 =   id    name   goal  
        1     raj    g1
        2     harsh  g3/g1
        3     ramu   g1
```

Above as you can see dataframe df1 and list li

i wanted to filter record in df1 base on list values of li but you can see in goal column first we need to split value base of / del but getting error

```
df1 = df1.filter(~df1.goal.isin(li))
```

but this is not returning any record...

is there any way to get record

Comment: i'm not entirely sure what you expect the output to be. can you please explain it more and add a sample of the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Using this exemple:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

li = ['g1','g2','g3']

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
    ('1','raj','g1'),
    ('2','harsh','g3/g1'),
    ('3','ramu','g1'),
    ('4','luiz','g2/g4')
    ],
    ["id", "name", "goal"]
)

df1.show()

# +---+-----+-----+
# | id| name| goal|
# +---+-----+-----+
# |  1|  raj|   g1|
# |  2|harsh|g3/g1|
# |  3| ramu|   g1|
# |  4| luiz|g2/g4|
# +---+-----+-----+
```

You can use `split` to split the goal column and then `array_except` to find which records are not in your list:

```
result = df1\
            .withColumn('goal_split', F.split(F.col('goal'), "/"))\
            .withColumn('li', F.array([F.lit(x) for x in li]))\
            .withColumn("test",F.array_except('goal_split','li'))\
            .filter(F.col('test') == F.array([]))\

result.show()

# +---+-----+-----+----------+------------+----+
# | id| name| goal|goal_split|          li|test|
# +---+-----+-----+----------+------------+----+
# |  1|  raj|   g1|      [g1]|[g1, g2, g3]|  []|
# |  2|harsh|g3/g1|  [g3, g1]|[g1, g2, g3]|  []|
# |  3| ramu|   g1|      [g1]|[g1, g2, g3]|  []|
# +---+-----+-----+----------+------------+----+
```

Than, select the columns you want for the result:

```
result.select('id', 'name', 'goal').show().

# +---+-----+-----+
# | id| name| goal|
# +---+-----+-----+
# |  1|  raj|   g1|
# |  2|harsh|g3/g1|
# |  3| ramu|   g1|
# +---+-----+-----+
```